# Null Pointer Exception while querying WFS Getfeature using Stored Query and getParameter

Tags: geoserver, wfs

This is my `StoredQuery`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="gemarkungsname">
    <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
            <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
                <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
                    </fes:PropertyName>
                    <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>
                </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </fes:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```

If I use `GEOSERVER/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=gemarkungsname&gemarkungsname=Mytown` I get a result.

I want to limit the amount of data and only query one property. But `GEOSERVER/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=gemarkungsname&gemarkungsname=Mytown&propertyName=gemarkungsname` shows me an error.

```
13 Dez 21:54:24 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 2.0.0
    baseUrl = http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/
    outputFormat = application/gml+xml; version=3.2
    resolve = none
    resolveDepth = *
    resolveTimeout = 300
    resultType = results
    abstractQueryExpressionGroup[0] = wfs:abstractQueryExpression=net.opengis.wfs20.impl.StoredQueryTypeImpl@4170d764 (handle: null) (id: gemarkungsname)
    abstractQueryExpression[0]:
        parameter[0]:
            name = gemarkungsname
            value = Mytown
        id = gemarkungsname
13 Dez 21:55:57 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
Request: getServiceInfo
13 Dez 21:55:57 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eDerivedStructuralFeatureID(BasicEObjectImpl.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eSet(BasicEObjectImpl.java:1068)
        at org.geotools.xsd.EMFUtils.set(EMFUtils.java:62)
        at org.geotools.xsd.EMFUtils.set(EMFUtils.java:312)
        at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.querySet(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:222)
        at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.read(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:97)
        at org.geoserver.wfs.kvp.v2_0.GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.read(GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java:31)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1548)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:691)
        at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:254)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is this query not possible? In the error message is at the beginning the text `(handle: null)` - this could be a hint for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, but without running in the debugger and looking at [line 222](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/kvp/GetFeatureKvpRequestReader.java#L222) I can't say for sure.